generic parameter is not narrowed down correctly in extends clause when using keyof operator
its basically simpler version of this question but using pure types and slightly cleaner example:
type TypedRouter<P extends string> = any

type Test<R> = R extends {
  [key: string]: any;
}
  ? {
      [P in keyof R]: TypedRouter<P>
//                                ^ 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'
    }
  : never;

if R extends {[key: string]: ...} then keyof R is string, so why P in keyof R is 'string | number | symbol' and not string?
work around for now is using & operator:
type Test<R> = R extends { [key: string]: any }
  ? {
      [P in keyof R]: TypedRouter<P & string>;
    }
  : never;

Playground

TS is behaving correctly. T extends U doesn't mean that the keys of T are constrained to keyof U. Extension can always add properties; e.g., {a: string, b: string} extends {a: string}.  String index signatures intentionally allow numeric keys (as per the docs), and extra symbol keys are not prevented because extra keys are not prevented. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

The definition R extends { [key: string]: any } does not restrict properties being keyed by numbers or symbols, because these are all possible key types in JavaScript objects, not just those that match the index signature.
E.g. the following code is type-correct:
type AType = {
    [key: string]: any;
}

const aConst: AType = {
    "aaa": 1,
    2: 2
}

To consider only string keys, you could use additional conditional type declaration:
type TypedRouter<P extends string> = any

type Test<R> = R extends {
  [key: string]: any;
}
  ? {
      [P in keyof R]: P extends string ? TypedRouter<P> : never // ensuring only string keys considered
    }
  : never;


Symbol keys are absolutely not converted to strings. Please [edit] this to fix it or your answer will attract downvotes.

@jcalz indeed, thanks for noticing that

IIUC, you want a Mapped Type to re-map a Dictionary of (something) into a Dictionary of TypedRouter's, but the latter needs a string type.
The TypedRouter<P & string> workaround works, but keeps incorrect keys (basically, it still re-maps them, but P & string produces a never type, that TypedRouter may handle or not):
type TypedRouter<P extends string> = P extends never ? "never" : "ok"

const s1 = Symbol(1)
type T = Test<{
  // ^? { 0: "never"; [s1]: "never"; str: "ok"; }
  0: 0,
  [s1]: 1,
  str: 2
}>

If you want to reject those keys during re-mapping, simply produce a never key:

You can filter out keys by producing never

In your case:
type Test2<R> = R extends {
  [key: string]: any;
}
  ? {
    [P in keyof R & string]: TypedRouter<P>
  }
  : never;

type T2 = Test2<{
  // ^? { str: "ok"; }
  0: 0,
  [s1]: 1,
  str: 2
}>

Playground Link

Even if number and symbol keys were excluded by string index signatures, it wouldn't be the source of this behavior.  The type T extends {[k: string]: any} prohibits almost nothing, since you can always have extra properties when extending a type.  T extends {a: any} allows {a: string, b: string} even though "b" is certainly not considered an "a", and it's not a bug. It's the way extension works.

Hum I see how the beginning of my answer takes a misleading way of focusing on quirks instead of the simple fact that the condition is almost always met. Please feel free to make it and answer.

How about this one?
type TypedRouter<P extends string> = { route: P };

type Test<R> = R extends { [key: string]: any }
  ? {
      [P in keyof R]: TypedRouter<P & string>;
    }
  : never;

// Example usage
type Example = {
  path1: string;
  path2: number;
  path3: boolean;
};

type Result = Test<Example>;

// Correct usage: Displaying type structure in a comment
// type Result should look like:
// {
//   path1: TypedRouter<"path1">;
//   path2: TypedRouter<"path2">;
//   path3: TypedRouter<"path3">;
// }

console.log("Type Result structured correctly.");

